# How to use eclipse-pmd rulesets configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

As I can see here: [In this manual](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/howtomakearuleset.html) It is easy to create rule set. I am using eclipse-pmd plugin. I just have difficulty figuring out where to put rulesets.properties file. Is it root of my source tree. My ruleset.xml is in root of my source tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up eclipse-pmd in the project properties.
Please take a look at the [getting started with eclipse-pmd](https://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/getting-started.html) page of the eclipse-pmd website. It has step-by-step instructions on how to set up the plugin.